# How to create SharePoint Survey with expiration date?

Tags: sharepoint, survey

I have custom Survey which have expiration date in RootWeb.Properties. How to redirect all users who want responde survey after expiration date (Click "Respond to Survey" or use direct link to NewForm.aspx) to custom page with some custom text (b.e. "This Survey has expired")?

Answer (score -1):

You can write an event receiver to achieve this. On the event receiver code you can check the expiration date and if it is expired, you can cancel item adding and redirect user to custom page. Note that your custom url must be a relative url.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);
       if (DateTime.Now > "your expiration date")
       {
           properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
           properties.RedirectUrl = "your custom url";
       }
   }
```

Comment: I think that this event receiver would execute when user filled all fields and click submit button. And I need redirect user when user click "Respond to Survey"